# Calendar read aloud feature

Tags: notifications, calendar

How can I make the Calendar read out its notifications and reminders out-loud? 3rd-party apps would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

[Talking Calendar Reminder App, Hongi Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.talkmecalendar.free) claims to do that.

> Speaks aloud calendar event reminders and alarms

I haven't used it, but a search in the play store turned that up.

Comment: Please link the app in future and quote the reason for recommending it. That's the way to do it on our site. Thanks